# @Model is null on MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my first question here at stackoverflow i tried to find an answer on similar posts, but really couldn't !
I'm new to MVC , sorry if the question is rather basic.
this is the problem :

**This is the Homecontroller code**

```
public ActionResult UserInfo(int? id)
{
    var result = new DataModel.MTN().MTNTBLUser.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id);
    return View(result);
}
```

**This is the HTML page results should appear**

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
    <div class="info">            
        <p>@Model.Name</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I JUST need the NAME that is in my user table , appear on that div section!
sorry for being so basic !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of `result` before you send it to the view?

Comment: Most likely your `result` is null.

Comment: @DavidG
it gets the ID of the user from table with this code: 
new DataModel.MTN().MTNTBLUser.FirstOrDefault
and put it into result

Comment: @MatiN are you sure that line works correctly? Have you tried putting a breakpoint before returning the view result and see if the model is populated?

Comment: @MatiN Yes, but is there an actual value in `result` or is it null? Using `FirstOrDefault` might give you null.

Comment: @DavidG What you just said actually solved my problem
i didn't mention to the id number up there !
Thank you so much ! 
can you write it down as the answer so that i mark it ?

Comment: @MatiN, it actually doesn't get the ID of the user, it pulls an object which has a current user's id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var result = new DataModel.MTN().MTNTBLUser.where(p=>p.id==id).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

```
@if(Model!=null){
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <div class="info">            
            <p>@Model.Name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```